# Captcha code validation using ajax in joomla

Tags: jquery

I want captcha code validation using ajax JQuery and php file that will validate catcha code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Joomla!, you can find builtin extensions that will do it for you "out of the box", just have a look here : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/captcha

Regards,

Max

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla go to backend and go through "Global Configuration".
Now click on Users->User Options tab.
There is dropdown "Captcha" that is I think selected none bydefault.
Please Select Captcha-Recaptcha.

That is it.

Now you have to setup captcha plugin from plugins.